# calculate a volume from eigenvalues in R

Tags: r, volume, eigenvalue

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will allow for me to simply generate the volume of a sphere from 6 generated eigen values.

So I have the data:

```
PCoA1  PCoA2  PCoA3  PCoA4  PCoA5  PCoA6 
3.2601 0.5313 0.1950 0.1174 0.0688 0.0494
```

And would like to convert to a volume. I'm assuming that all values have equal weighting. Is this possible in R?

Thanks

Comment: I've forgotten enough linear algebra that I could be totally misunderstanding you, but this sounds like you're asking for the volume of a 6 dimensional ellipsoid. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Are these the result of a principle coordinates analysis? You are looking for the sphere encompassing your data?

Comment: Sure thing. So you arebasically right, im trying to plot the volume of an ellipsoid based on these readings. I'm not sure how much I can elaborate further, i'm pretty new at this so was just trying to get a grip on fundamentals! The values were calculated using betadisper {vegan}

Comment: You might want to ask on stats.stackexchange.com, see this question for the 2-d case: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9898/how-to-plot-an-ellipse-from-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation would be easier in math.SE

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area) says that the n-volume of a n-ball of radius R is: π^(n/2) × R^n / Γ(n/2 + 1).

For n=6 this hypervolume is  π^3 × R^6 / 6.

In your case of a hyperellipsoid I would expect to replace R^6 with the product of your six eigenvalues, taking them as semiaxes of the hyperellipsoid.